# Moodle Scorm Player vs Articulate Mobile Player on Android Devices

Tags: moodle, scorm

I've tested Articulate Storyline Courses on Moodle 2.7 and Android Articulate Mobile Player.
In Mobile Player all courses working fine while in Moodle 2.7 courses running slow in Scorm player and sound problem occurs.

I would like to know about how we can play Storyline 2(scorm) courses on Android devices perfectly. If you have any idea, please share

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know that some people have found that publishing Storyline 1 courses using the mobile player and Tin Can tracking led to significant performance improvements especially for multimedia. This was not specific to Moodle. Perhaps the same applies to Storyline 2. Please try it and let us know.

I recommend posting your question on the [Articulate forums](https://community.articulate.com/discuss) as you may get a response from somebody with experience with this issue in Storyline 2. Please include a screenshot of your publish settings and/or share your file.

Here's a link to a site about [Tin Can tracking](http://tincanapi.com?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=main?pmc=em-1).

If you want to test the package against another LMS to confirm if the problem is Moodle specific (I suspect not) you could try [SCORM Cloud](http://cloud.scorm.com?utm_source=cloud_scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=scorm_cloud?pmc=em-1) for free.